# How to validate image upload in Angular Reactive Form

Tags: angular

In my Angular-12 project, I have this code for image upload:

```js
imageSrcLogo!: string;

onFileChange(event: any) {
  const reader = new FileReader();

  if (event.target.files && event.target.files.length) {
    const [file] = event.target.files;
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = () => {
      this.imageSrcLogo = reader.result as string;
      this.companyInfoForm.patchValue({
        fileSource: reader.result
      });
    };
  }
}

this.companyInfoForm = this.fb.group({
  companyLogo: ['', [Validators.required]],
});

get fc() {
  return this.companyInfoForm.controls;
};
```

```html
<div class="text-center">
  <img class="profile-user-img img-fluid img-circle" [src]="imageSrcLogo || 'assets/img/no-image.png'" alt="No Company Logo" style="height:150px; width:150px">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="file"></label>
  <input formControlName="companyLogo" id="file" type="file" class="form-control" (change)="onFileChange($event)">
</div>
```

I am using Reactive Form.

How do I validate the image type to be:  png, jpec, gif and svg?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So, the returned value from the readAsDataUrl() function is a string with a format such as this : "data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjQKJeLjz9MKNCAw...", As you can see, there is a valid mime type in that string and all we have to do is strip out what we do not need and verify if the file is of the desired mimetype.

```
reader.onload = e => {
      
      const mime = e.target.result.split(";")[0].split(":")[1]);
      if (['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif', 'image/svg+xml'].includes(mime)) {
         this.imageSrcLogo = e.target.result as string;
         this.companyInfoForm.patchValue({
            fileSource: e.target.result
         });
      } else {
         alert('The file format is not supported');
      }
}
```

Comment: It highlights this:  reader.result.split    and gives an error:   Object is possibly 'null'.ts(2531)

Comment: Alright, i thought this was already working for you... but what you can do is reader.onload = e => {

and then instead of reader.result ... use e.target.result

Comment: I am going to make an  edit on my answer to reflect this change

Comment: curious as to why it would be null in an onload() function though. Hope you found a work around